# Shooting a projectile in the direction of a LineRenderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `LineRenderer` composed of 3 points. I want to shoot a projectile from the second point in the direction of the third.

I tried to get both positions, instantiate at the second and shoot forward in direction of the third, but my projectiles were a little bit shifted from where they should go.

There is the method to shoot the projectile that I used previously and that worked when I had a `LineRenderer` with only 2 points. I got the idea from https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/brick-shooter.

```
public void Shoot()
{
    shotPosL = laserPointerL.GetComponent<Transform>();           //get the position of the beginning of the laser pointer
    Rigidbody shotL = Instantiate(projectile, shotPosL.position, shotPosL.rotation) as Rigidbody;      //instantiate a new projectile 
    shotL.AddForce(shotPosL.forward * shotForce);             //throw the projectile in the direction of the laser pointer
}
```

But since I added a third point to my `LineRenderer`, the projectiles simply go straight from the middle of the screen and backward.

Edit: Someone judged that my message is not useful or clear, I'm sorry, it's difficult to explain. There is my current code if it helps.

```
public void Shoot()
{
    Quaternion noRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);

    LineRenderer laserL = laserPointerL.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    Vector3 kneeLeftPosition = laserL.GetPosition(1);
    Vector3 laserLeftTarget = laserL.GetPosition(2);
    Rigidbody shotL = Instantiate(projectile, kneeLeftPosition, noRotation) as Rigidbody;      //instantiate a new projectile 
    shotL.AddForce(laserLeftTarget * shotForce);             //throw the projectile in the direction of the laser pointer
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use GetPosition() or GetPositions() on the LineRenderer component to get the position and directions you need?

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html

Comment: Yep, that's what I did, but the projectiles do not go exactly where my LineRenderer is pointing, there is always a little shifting.

Comment: When you are calling 'shotL.AddForce(laserLeftTarget * shotForce);' you are giving it the position of the left target, you should be providing a direction. You can get the direction of the second point to the third point by subtracting the vectors e.g. var direction = thirdPoint - secondPoint;

Comment: Ok, I don't exactly understand why this operation give a direction, but it works! I'll have to learn more about vector. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you normalize the direction you got from subtracting the vectors, otherwise your direction will be scaled and can affect your movement rate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your points are defined as

```
Vector3 point1;
Vector3 point2;
```

Your force from 1 to 2 should have a direction (point2-point1) - you should subtract the start point from the end point to get direction.
use

```
rb.AddForce.((point2-point1).normalized*shotForce);
```